# pandas dataframe concatenation issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Still learning pandas, so please excuse if the question seems naive. I have two dataframes with different number of rows. I want to join them along axis 1.

df1:

```
Myidx col1 col2 col3
0    a     b    c
1    d     e    f
2    g     h    i
3    j     k    l
```

df2:

```
idx col4  col5  col6
 0     m      n     p
```

resulting df should look like:

```
idx col1 col2 col3  col4  col5  col6
0    a     b    c    m     n     p
1    d     e    f
2    g     h    i
3    j     k    l
```

I am able to append it to the bottom but joining them along axis1 is not working.
I tried using following two things. (The resulting csv file does not even show df2)

```
1) df1.join(df2)
2) pd.concat([df1,df2], axis =1)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
dfnew = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Myidx', right_on='idx', suffixes=(False, False)).reset_index()
```

should do you

or look at the merging guide.

[Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)